# NSManagedObject is automatically set to fault

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

I have the following classes:

```
class Profile {
  var state:State
  var member:Member?
}

class Member: NSManagedObject {
   @NSManaged var nickName: String?
   @NSManaged var mId: String?
}
```

The problem is located in the following class:

```
class RegisterMultiTableVContr: UITableViewController {

     var profile:Profile?

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         self.profileService.createEmptyProfile(
                 { (profile:Profile) in
                     self.profile = profile
                     println("\(self.profile!.member!.description)")
                     /*
                     Correct:
                     Output:
                     <meetpoll.Member: 0x7fd654175c10> (entity: Member; id: 0xd000000000c80000<x-coredata://21228B23-63B3-4708-8EAC-3302072BA074/Member/p5> ; data: {
                         mId = nil;
                         nickName = nil;
                     })
                     */
                 }, failure: { (error:String) in
                     // Exception Handling
             })
     }

     override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
         println("\(self.profile!.member!.description)")
         /*
         Set to fault automatically
         Output:
         <meetpoll.Member: 0x7fd654175c10> (entity: Member; id: 0xd000000000c80000<x-coredata://21228B23-63B3-4708-8EAC-3302072BA074/Member/p50> ; 
         data: <fault>)
         */
     }
}
```

The prepareForSegue function is called only after the viewDidLoad. I wrote the output of the println function into the source code.
My question is, why the object member is set to fault automatically? and how can i set the member fault to false again?

**Include 2014-10-08**

The function create an empty profile with Member object like this:

```
var member = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Member", inManagedObjectContext: context) as Member
var profile = Profile(member:member)
var error: NSError? = nil
if context.save(&error) {
   return profile
}
```

**Include 2014-10-09**

Ok i see you need more information, so I wrote a mini simple example and loaded up to GitHub https://github.com/qeychon/CoreDataBug/tree/master

Comment: is this really a problem? fault just means that the information isn't in memory, but it will be fetched if you need it... there are some cases that you should care about it, if you are doing a bunch of custom sorting or something... but in generally you just should use the default faulting behavior

Comment: Faults are normal and should be expected.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. The question is, If I create an object with insertNewObjectForEntityForName and save, then I can change the attributes shortly thereafter. On this example, I see that the same object is sometime set to fault. What caused this change?

Comment: The save caused the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: @quellish you´re right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the first object could be changed: the Core Data functions are performed asynchronously. Therefore, the object could be changed temporarily. After a certain time the method save is called (thank you @quellish) and suddenly the object has been set to read only (fault). The solution: the save method must be called later!

Answer (score 1):

You could set

```
[request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO]
```

**Update**

Sorry for the delay I was answering from iPhone app

As quellish say there is nothing wrong getting faults when fetching from CoreData.
Each of the objects will be 'fault' until you need to access their persistent values and you can force core data to retrieve the full object with the persistent values by setting

```
[request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO]
```

Comment: @GameDroids, I do not see what is ambiguous here. Adi Pop is saying on the fetch request, set `returnsObjectsAsFaults` to NO. So that Core Data does not return objects as faults from a fetch. Faults are the default behavior, and should *always* be expected.

Comment: However, I have not implemented a FetchRequest, so I cannot set the fault status. I added this to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why it is set to fault automatically, it seems like something else is being called in-between them. You can easily turn your object into fault or full object with

- [NSManagedObjectContext refreshObject:o mergeChanges: YES/NO ]

Where YES goes for an object and NO goes for a fault.

Comment: Core Data returns faults by default.

Comment: Yeah, but not when you create them. Here the object is created and then turned into a fault between two callbacks from the OS

Comment: If I set the mergeChanges to true or false, then it is always fault. This is realy strange

Comment: Ok I've checked this in Swift, but this had no effect. After managedObjectContext!.refreshObject(obj, mergeChanges: true) or false, I can change the attribute of obj.

Comment: Merge changes true/false affects cd row cache, not necessarily the faultless. If object is in row cache getting it from fault is blazing fast.